# SWIG Java wrapping C++ interface that extends interface(s)

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, java-native-interface, swig

Looking for advice on handling complex C++ interface inheritance structures via SWIG/Java:

I'm using SWIG to generate bindings for a large C++ codebase. We have a common paradigm, where we have an `IRefCount` pure virtual class:

```
class IRefCount
{
public:
    virtual void AddRef() = 0;
    virtual void Release() = 0;
};
```

that many of our other C++ interfaces extend, e.g.:

```
class A: public IRefCount
{
public
    virtual void MethodA() = 0;
}
```

or

```
class B: public IRefCount, public C
{
public
    virtual void MethodB() = 0;
}
```

where `C` is another C++ pure virtual class that B extends.

Recently, I've been trying to wrap these as Java interfaces, because SWIG by default just uses the first listed base class as the one to use when generating the Java wrapper class--and I was running into situations where this was masking needed APIs inherited from `C`.

I added the following to my SWIG interface:

```
%include "swiginterface.i"
%interface_impl(IRefCount);
%interface_impl(A);
%interface_impl(B);
%interface_impl(C);
```

and was able to generate/compile the bindings just fine. However, I'm running into a runtime exception when SWIG tries to init, due to the fact that the proxy class for A (for example) implements the extended interface (IRefCount), when the underlying C++ class doesn't:

```
public class ASwigImpl implements A, IRefCount {
...
  public void AddRef() {
    ExampleJNI.ASwigImpl_AddRef(swigCPtr, this);
  }

  public void Release() {
    ExampleJNI.ASwigImpl_Release(swigCPtr, this);
  }
...
}
```

Compiles fine, but at run time I see:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: SwigDirector_ASwigImpl_AddRef
        at com.example.ExampleJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
        at com.example.ExampleJNI.<clinit>(ExampleJNI.java:1734)
...
...
...
```

Is there a way to handle this kind of inheritance structure via SWIG in Java? Or is it impossible due to Java not allowing multiple inheritance/not allowing classes to extend interfaces?

Comment: Since Java does not support multiple inheritance, I would introduce a class `IRefCountC`, which is the union of `IRefCount` and `C` and wrap this interface.